# Conditional formatting does not work or formula is incorrect

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My formula checks for value in 7 cells merged together and outputs `TRUE` if value meets the condition. Formula works fine when I apply it to every cell individually as shown on the image, but when I try to use the same formula in conditional formatting to highlight range of cells that meets criteria, nothing happens.

Here is my formula:

```
=IF($B$9<>1,FALSE,AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(12,COLUMN(Z$11)-IF(WEEKDAY(Z$11)=1,6,(WEEKDAY(Z$11)-2))))>=$L14,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(12,COLUMN(Z$11)-IF(WEEKDAY(Z$11)=1,6,(WEEKDAY(Z$11)-2))))<=$R14))
```

[image]

Basically what my formula does is checks if date in the merged cell is either grater or equal to the date of the other cell (Start Date) and smaller or equal to the End Date, which is also defined in another cell.

I cannot seem to get it to work.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need that formula(maybe I misunderstood) but an example is as follows;

Edited:

Maybe you can use a dummy (not merged) row.[image]

Row 5 is conditionally formatted based on row 7th values. 
Please note that,

1) Formula in the 7th row is seen in the formula bar.

2) Conditionally format range(not shown in the pic) is 5th row.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the reason I need this particular formula is to highlight 7 cells in the different row based on the condition that this formula checks. and not the merged cells. Thanks again

Comment: @AlexB Edited my answer. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Dude, you are a STAR, Thanks a lot. I have just discovered that apparently INDIRECT function will not work when used in conditional formatting is surrounded by and AND function, this is why my initial formula was not working.

Comment: @AlexB you are welcome. In fact I know an important flaw of indirect(trace dependency does not show indirectly called cells), but didnt use it in a conditional formatting.